# How to compaire a string using wildcard characters in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I'm working in xslt, I have to test a string with another string as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="$mesg = 'this is message of method add*'">
    ....
    ....
    .....
</xsl:if>
```

I have to test "mesg" variable content with the text that i have added in above code with anything following the string, Currently i tried using "*" wildcard character. But it doesn't work.

Thanks and regards,
BSalunke

Comment: In this case [starts-with(string1,string2)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) function helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 does not have any "wildcard support", XSLT 2.0 introduces regular expression support however.
As has already been pointed out, for your simple check with XSLT 1.0 it should suffice to test

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with($mesg, 'this is a message of method add')">
```

If you switch to XSLT 2.0 (by using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or like AltovaXML) you can use [the `matches` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches) and regular expressions e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="matches($mesg, '^this is a message of method add.*')">
```